# Missing $ inserted in block environment

Tags: beamer, errors

I tried to compile the following using the `beamer` class:

```
\begin{block}
    $$T(\mathcal{P})=\mathbb{R}$$  and 
 $$\mathrm{M}(\mathcal{P})=\mathbb{R}_{+}^{3}/ \mathrm{S}_3$$
\end{block}
```

If I complie the math stuff alone, it works just fine, but when I put them inside a `block` environment, it says `missing $ inserted`.

What should I do?

Comment: It's not related with your question, but I think you should read [`Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/1952)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `block`-environment needs a title:

```
\begin{block}{TITLE}
Your Text
\end{block}
```

you can get rid of the title for example if you use a space:

```
\begin{block}{\ }
...
\end{block}
```

At least, this solved your problem on my slides

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that. In fact puting {} did the job.

Comment: ... and so if you don't supply a title, it grabs the next token as one which, in this case, is `$`, and this causes it to get *very* confused.  Note that there is a difference between `{\ }` and `{}` since `{\ }` specifies a title which happens to be a space but `{}` says "There's no title" and beamer treats the two differently.

Comment: that ist true, the option with `{\ }` adds a little space above the content inside the `block` environment, which is kind of nice in my opinion